# Catching multiple SIGCHLD processes for Unix Style Shell in C

Tags: c, shell, signals, sigchld

I am writing an extensible shell am I am working on an issue related to catching SIGCHLD signals from a Unix kernel.

I am trying to maintain a list of current jobs (so when the user types "jobs" into the shell I can return the appropriate jobs). The issue arises when I need to remove jobs from the list. I'd like to remove them from the list when I receive a SIGCHLD signal letting me know the process is terminated.

There are two issues:
1. When I receive a SIGCHLD signal, how do I know which child sent that signal?
2. How do I deal if multiple SIGCHLD signals are received and they do not get queued so I'll only see the first SIGCHLD return?

Thank you!

Comment: Refer to this post, this answers your first question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595503/determine-pid-of-terminated-process

Comment: @user376507: It actually answers both questions. Good find. Marked as dup.